# Short story: lone gunman disrupts an economy

Tags: identification-request

I'm trying to remember a short story I read in high school about a sniper or lone gunman who fires into a parade of crowded people, killing dozens and, through a chain of events, disrupts the entire political and economic stability of the country (which was his intent from the start). He isn't tried or even caught for his crime by the end of the story. And I remember the description of the shooting to be fairly graphic in nature.

The story is somewhat of a dystopian tale set in an unnamed country.

Any ideas?